# React: How to collapse all the all open children nodes if their parent node is closing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]
I am using react. I am able to generate a tree from xml file.
Please find my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-snow-nfce4i
Please find the attached image.
The code is working fine in Visual Studio. I am not sure how to use sandbox, not able to understand sandbox error.

Currently, tree is working fine. Collapse/Minimize of the expanded/open children nodes are not working if their parent node is collapsing.

Please check my code and see where the code needs change.

Thanks a lot.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ProductsTree from "./ProductsTreeView";
const initialState = {
  currentNode: {},
  data: ""
};
export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.setCurrentNode = this.setCurrentNode.bind(this);
  }
  setCurrentNode(node) {
    this.setState({ currentNode: node });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProductsTree setCurrentNode={this.setCurrentNode} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
______________________________________________________
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import XMLParser from "react-xml-parser";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import tree from "./tree.xml";
class ProductsTreeView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="TreeView">
        <TreeView setCurrentNode={this.props.setCurrentNode} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Node {
  description = "n/a";
  id = -1;
  key_id = -1;
  linkpagename = "";
  isActive = false;
  nodes = [];
  constructor(description, id, key_id, linkpagename) {
    this.description = description;
    this.id = id;
    this.key_id = key_id;
    this.linkpagename = linkpagename;
  }

  static nodesFromXml(xml) {
    const map = (entity, nodes) => {
      const id = entity.attributes["id"];
      const key_id = entity.attributes["key-id"];
      const descriptionText =
        entity.children[
          entity.children.findIndex((child) => child.name === "description")
        ].value;
      const entities = entity.children.filter(
        (child) => child.name === "entity"
      );

      var linkPageName = entity.attributes["link-page-name"];
      linkPageName = linkPageName.replace(".aspx", "");
      const node = new Node(descriptionText, id, key_id, linkPageName);
      nodes.push(node);
      entities.forEach((entity) => map(entity, node.nodes));
    };
    const parsedData = new XMLParser().parseFromString(xml);
    const entities = parsedData.children.filter(
      (child) => child.name === "entity"
    );

    const nodes = [];
    entities.forEach((entity) => map(entity, nodes));
    return nodes;
  }
}

class TreeView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { nodes: [] };
    this.toggleNode = this.toggleNode.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(tree, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
      .then((response) =>
        this.setState({ nodes: Node.nodesFromXml(response.data) })
      )
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
  }
  render() {
    const nodes = this.state.nodes
    return (
      <ul>
        {nodes.map((node) => (
          <TreeNode
            id={node.id}
            key={node.key_id}
            node={node}
            onToggle={this.toggleNode}
            setCurrentNode={this.props.setCurrentNode}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
  toggleNode(node) {
    this.props.setCurrentNode(node);
    function _toggleNode(currentNode, node) {
      if (currentNode.id === node.id) {
        //currentNode.id === node.id)

        {
          if (currentNode.key_id === node.key_id) {
            currentNode.isActive = !currentNode.isActive;
          }
        }
      } else {
        currentNode.nodes.forEach((childNode) => _toggleNode(childNode, node));
      }
    }
    const nodes = this.state.nodes;
    nodes.forEach((currentNode) => _toggleNode(currentNode, node));
    this.setState((state) => (state.nodes = nodes));
  }
}
class TreeNode extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const node = this.props.node;
    const onToggle = this.props.onToggle;
    let activeChildren = null;
    if (node.isActive && node.nodes.length > 0) {
      activeChildren = (
        <ul>
          {node.nodes.map((node) => (
            <TreeNode
              id={node.id}
              key={node.key_id}
              node={node}
              onToggle={onToggle}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }

    return (
      <li
        id={node.id}
        linkpagename={node.linkpagename}
        key={node.key_id}
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.stopPropagation();
          onToggle(node);
        }}
      >
        <Link
          to={node.linkpagename}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#000000" }}
        >[![enter image description here][3]][3]
          {node.description}
        </Link>{" "}
        - {node.key_id} - {node.linkpagename}
        {activeChildren}
      </li>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductsTreeView;

<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<tree>
       <entity id="e11" key-id="1" link-page-name="Add_Category">
              <description>Service</description>
              <image>images/plus.gif</image>
              <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>
              <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>
              <entity id="e248" key-id="48" link-page-name="Edit_Category">
                     <description>A_test1_test1</description>
                     <image>images/plus.gif</image>
                     <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>
                     <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>
                     <entity id="e3717" key-id="717" link-page-name="Edit_Product">
                           <description>A_SubItem1</description>
                           <image>images/plus.gif</image>
                           <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>
                           <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>
                           <entity id="e45546" key-id="5546" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">
                                  <description>A_Test_Template</description>
                                  <image>images/paper.gif</image>
                                  <imageOpen>images/paper.gif</imageOpen>
                           </entity>
                     </entity>
              </entity>
              <entity id="e247" key-id="47" link-page-name="Edit_Category">
                     <description>A_test6</description>
                     <image>images/plus.gif</image>
                     <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>
                     <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>
                     <entity id="e3716" key-id="716" link-page-name="Edit_Product">
                           <description>A_Item</description>
                           <image>images/plus.gif</image>
                           <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>
                           <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>
                           <entity id="e45545" key-id="5545" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">
                                  <description>temp1</description>
                                  <image>images/paper.gif</image>

                                  <imageOpen>images/paper.gif</imageOpen>
                           </entity>
                     </entity>
              </entity>
       </entity>

       <entity id="e12" key-id="2" link-page-name="Add_Category">

              <description>Sales</description>

              <image>images/plus.gif</image>

              <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>

              <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>

              <entity id="e230" key-id="30" link-page-name="Edit_Category">

                     <description>Gift Cards</description>

                     <image>images/plus.gif</image>

                     <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>

                     <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>

                     <entity id="e3421" key-id="421" link-page-name="Edit_Product">

                           <description>Sample Card</description>

                           <image>images/plus.gif</image>

                           <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>

                           <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>

                           <entity id="e43308" key-id="3308" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">

                                  <description>greeting temp</description>

                                  <image>images/paper.gif</image>

                                  <imageOpen>images/paper.gif</imageOpen>

                           </entity>

                     </entity>

                     <entity id="e3422" key-id="422" link-page-name="Edit_Product">

                           <description>De Card</description>

                           <image>images/plus.gif</image>

                           <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>

                           <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>

                           <entity id="e43309" key-id="3309" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">

                                  <description>NS Temp</description>

                                  <image>images/paper.gif</image>

                                  <imageOpen>images/paper.gif</imageOpen>

                           </entity>

                     </entity>

 

              </entity>

              <entity id="e215" key-id="15" link-page-name="Edit_Category">

                     <description>Chck</description>

                     <image>images/plus.gif</image>

                     <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>

                     <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>

                     <entity id="e3671" key-id="671" link-page-name="Edit_Product">

                           <description>Add item</description>

                           <image>images/plus.gif</image>

                           <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>

                           <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>

                           <entity id="e45438" key-id="5438" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">

                                  <description>Ahhhh</description>

                                  <image>images/paper.gif</image>

                                  <imageOpen>images/paper.gif</imageOpen>

                           </entity>

                     </entity>

                     <entity id="e3450" key-id="450" link-page-name="Edit_Product">

                           <description>Advtttt</description>

                           <image>images/plus.gif</image>

                           <imageNode>images/de.gif</imageNode>

                           <imageOpen>images/minus.gif</imageOpen>

                           <entity id="e43577" key-id="3577" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">

                                  <description>gggggg</description>

                                  <image>images/paper.gif</image>

                                  <imageOpen>images/paper.gif</imageOpen>

                           </entity>

                     </entity>

              </entity>

 

       </entity>

</tree>
```

Comment: Try to provide a minimum reproducible example with your question - it can help you to figure out the answer as well. This is too much code for people to read just to find the part that has to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `toggleNode` handler's internal `_toggleNode` function to take a third parameter, we'll call it `isActive` that if set to any non-undefined value will set the current node's `isActive` property to *that* value, otherwise do the normal node toggling. Add an additional check that if the node was *just* toggled inactive to recurse on *that* node's subtree and pass an `isActive` value of false to deactivate all nodes in that subtree.

```
toggleNode(node) {
  const { nodes } = this.state;
  this.props.setCurrentNode(node);

  function _toggleNode(currentNode, node, isActive) {
    if (isActive !== undefined) {
      currentNode.isActive = isActive;
    } else if (currentNode.id === node.id) {
      if (currentNode.key_id === node.key_id) {
        currentNode.isActive = !currentNode.isActive;
      }
    }
    currentNode.nodes.forEach((childNode) =>
      _toggleNode(childNode, node, currentNode.isActive ? undefined : false)
    );
  }

  nodes.forEach((currentNode) => _toggleNode(currentNode, node));

  this.setState((state) => (state.nodes = nodes));
}
```

[image: Edit react-how-to-collapse-all-the-all-open-children-nodes-if-their-parent-node-is-c]

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew for helping me in finding the solution. I will look into it. Highly appreciate for your help.

Comment: Thanks Drew. Expand/collapse nodes functionality is working fine. I am adding two links ExpandAll and CollapseAll. How to pass isActive so that ExpandAll link expand all the nodes if the nodes are collapsed. CollapseAll link collapse all the nodes if nodes are expanded.

Comment: Thanks Drew. Collapse/Expand node is working fine. I am adding two links ExpandAll and CollapseAll. ExpandAll link expand all the nodes if the nodes are collapsed, collapse all collapsed all the nodes. How to pass isActive? Thanks again

Comment: Hi Drew, I added two links in App.js .  How to pass isActive true and false using expand and collapse functions to expand all nodes or collapse all nodes.          
 <Link onClick={() => {this.ExpandAll(); }}><b>Expand</b></Link>

<Link onClick={() => {this.CollapseAll(); }}><b>Minimize</b></Link>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249257/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-testuser).